# a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm using numpy for reading an arff file and I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

I used `np.isnan(X2.any())` and `np.isfinite(X2.all())`to check if it's a `nan` or infinite case. But it's none of these. This means it's the third case, which is `infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to take care of this error.

Thanks.

Comment: I am a little confused: how can you check that you don't have NaN's in the data (`X2`?) when you can't read it? Can you clarify this?

Comment: Do you have values greater than `1.7976931348623157e+308` in your data (`numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).max`)?

Comment: @EOL : I am able to read the data just fine. I am getting this error after I read the elements and try to make a prediction over the data using Random Forests etc.

Comment: `np.isnan(X2.any())` performs the operations in the wrong order. I think you want `np.isnan(X2).any()`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker : No there is no value greater than (numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).max) in my data. But now I am clueless what is causing the error. Let me try interjay's suggestion

Comment: Thanks @interjay : You are right. Now it shows there are NaN values. But I used `imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=1)
imp.fit(X2)` to replace NaN values with the median. Any idea why it still has NaN values ?

Comment: It sounds like that error is actually being raised by a `scikit-learn` call (maybe in `RandomForestClassifier.fit()`?). Please always post the full error traceback in your question, and clearly mention which libraries you are actually using.

Answer (score 8):

Ok I got it. After i used `Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=1) imp.fit(X2)`. I also had to write :

`X2 = imp.fit_transform(X2)`. The reason being  sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.fit_transform returns a new array, it doesn't alter the argument array

Comment: So this was a misunderstanding on your part; could you close/delete your original question?